# PHP @Mail gives set false always

Tags: php, email, wamp, wampserver

Hi my php mail functions always results false i have even made the call function mail() on the code but it remains then altered the code by declaring a variable $f and still no good

```
    <?php

$message="";
$f="";
$mail_sent="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$_POST['email']."\r\n";


    $recipient="iam@myweb.com";


    $subject = "CONTACT MAIL LETTER\n";
    $message .= "<span style='font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;'>Dear Sir, <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"."<br> Contact Us details are displayed below <br><br>";   

    $message.='<tr><td><b><u>CONTACT US DETAILS</u></b></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';

    $message.="<BR><BR><b>FIRST NAME:</b> ".$_POST['fname'].  "<BR><BR>";

    $message.="<BR><BR><b>LAST NAME:</b> ".$_POST['lname'].  "<BR><BR>"; 

     $message.="<b>E-MAIL ADDRESS:</b> ".$_POST['email'].  "<BR><BR>";

     $message.="<b>SUBJECT:</b> ".$_POST['subject'].  "<BR><BR>";   

     $message.="<b>MESSAGE:</b> ".$_POST['message'].  "<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>";

     $message .= "Thanks,<BR>".$_POST['fname']. "</span>";
     //echo $message;


    $mail_sent = @mail($recipient,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if($mail_sent)
    {
    $f=1 ;
    }
    else
    {
    $f=0;
    }
    }

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if($f==1)
         {
            echo "Your Mail has been sent Successfully.";
          }
       else
       {
        echo "Your Mail has not been sent Successfully.";
       }
}
?>
```

The above functions always echo unsuccsfull

Comment: Does it return `false` even if the mail is sent successfully?

Comment: remove `@` from `mail`

Comment: The `@` is an error control operator, not actually a 'part' of the function: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Since you tagged the question `wampserver` I'm guessing that you installed the package and now you want it to send emails. But setting up a mail server is a bit more complicated than that and can't be explained in a single answer here. I don't know this WampServer, but it doesn't look like it comes with any mail server software.

Comment: I removed @ but still i get the same message and the mail have never sent to the recipient and do return false

Comment: You don't need to compare `$mail_sent` and set `$f` since they should always be the same. `$mail_sent=1` for success, `$mail_sent=0` for failure.

Comment: Wampserver must be configured with local mail server if you plan to use `mail()`. This is not a PHP problem but a Wampserver mail server configuration issue.

Comment: PHP `mail()` does not actually send mail, it just passes an email to a local mail server. WAMPServer runs on Windows. Windows does not have a mail server by default. I would suggest you look at `phpMailer` and use your yahoo/google/other SMTP mail account to send email. Alternatively you can install something like `hMailer` which can work well for testing purposes, but it is unlikely any mail from that will be accepted by real mail servers as you will not be recognised as a ligitimate sender of emails.